# MySQL to oracle connector

Tags: mysql, oracle

Is there a way to transparently translate MySQL queries to oracle back-end?
I have an application written to use MySQL but I want data to be stored in oracle. Is there a way to avoid code modification and use Oracle as back-end database?

Comment: I don't know for sure, but my guess is no. If you decide to restructure, make sure you use an abstraction layer like PDO: http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php that will help you immensely with using multiple DMBSs

Comment: I don't think that this is possible. You'd need a fake MySQL-Driver which redirects everything to the Oracle-Database. What application and what language?

Comment: Is there any storage engine for mysql to transparently store data in Oracle like one for IBM DB2?